# Python : Inheritance from one class, child classes give TypeError

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two classes that inherit from the same base class but do not want to play with each other, such are the young ones indeed.

```
class A() : 
  ...

class B(A) : 
  ...

class C(A) : 
  ...

b=B()
c=C()
c.method(b)
```

gives me a TypeError of c and b are not the same, what does python need to think that they are the same ? Is there some __SpecialThingIDontKnowAbout__ property/method one should implement or not ? Or is there some trick to class design that I'm missing

To be particular I am inheriting TreeDict() as follows :

```
class TNode(TreeDict):
 def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs) : 
  super(TNode, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class LNode(TreeDict):
 def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs) : 
  super(LNode, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

TN = TNode(); TN.A = 1
LN = LNode(); LN.A = 1
LN.attach('TN',TN)
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "JSONE.py", line 430, in <module>
  LN.attach(TN)
TypeError: descriptor 'attach' requires a 'treedict.treedict.TreeDict' ...
object but received a 'type'
```

I do understand that the children are of 'type' and 'treedict^3' is required but how do I get the children to mimic this behaviour ?

EDIT :

Hmm... it started working now, not that I did anything different from what I can see in the undo/redo history (Thanks all)

Comment: could you post the exact error that you get (full traceback)

Comment: Change the commas in the assignment statements to semicolons:  `TN = TNode(); TN.A = 1`  _(this isn't the answer, but it fixes a syntax error in the question)_

Comment: @dsh and chepner Fixed the Typos

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian gave the full traceback the ellipsis are to prevent the code pane from scrolling.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573519/python-unable-to-inherit-from-a-c-extension That is a C extension library, right?

Comment: It is a C library from what I understand, I see [link](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) says to make an adapter for the class. Your link seems to suggst the same thing if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Where does TreeDict come from?  I don't think that's from the standard library.  I think your question is really about TreeDict and not Python inheritance.

Comment: @PeterGraham I got it from here [link](http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoytak/code/treedict/api.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the TreeDict type doesn't allow subclassing.  I found it in the [treedict](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/treedict) package.  The TreeDict type itself is written in Cython.  The culprit is this block of code in the `attach()` method (around line 1910 of treedict.pyx):

```
    if type(tree_or_key) is str:
        key = <str>tree_or_key
    elif type(tree_or_key) is TreeDict:
        if tree is not None:
            raise TypeError("Only one TreeDict instance can be given to attach.")

        tree = <TreeDict>tree_or_key
        key = None
    else:
        raise TypeError("`tree_or_key` must be either a string or TreeDict instance.")
```

Change the `elif type(tree_or_key) is TreeDict:` line to `elif isinstance(tree_or_key, TreeDict):` and submit a patch to the project.  You might want to check the rest of treedict.pyx for other occurrences of the same bug.

Comment: Ok, cool thank you very much. I'll do the patching in the morning.

Comment: My code started working again without changing this though so I'm somewhat perplexed by that. I've marked you down for the answer though for now.

Comment: @Carel: I've got the expected error: `TypeError: tree_or_key must be either a string or TreeDict instance.` so dsh's fix should work. But it is not the error that you provided in the question. I've tested on Python 2.7 and treedict 0.12

Comment: That error is due to the attach operation i.e. when you run LN.attach(TN) it throws that error, you have to give it a name so LN.attach('name',TN) I'll fix the code above, thanks