# Add attribute to object in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to add an attribute to the CSVreader object:

```
import csv
csvfile = open(inputfilepath, 'rb')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
setattr(csv_reader, 'nrows', countRows(csvfile))
```

Receiving this error:

> AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'nrows'

Comment: Why do you even want to do this?

Comment: Well, subclassing the reader won't work.  I tried, just to see what would happen, and ended up slamming into something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573519/python-unable-to-inherit-from-a-c-extension ---which seems rude, but maybe try the trick noted in the answer there?